# Permanently deactivated Wifi after failed update of the Ubuntu 23.10 release files (for a newer installer type)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

The Hp ProBook 4730s Wifi on off switch is out of effect since I have started the update for the Ubuntu 23.10 release files (application of a newer installer type) over the internet during an installation.
I have interrupted the update process of the installation files after a time of popping up of an error message box with the same contents and my confirmation every time the box occurred.
However, the result is now a permanently deactivated Wifi.
In normal operation, the Wifi operation Led changes its color from amber to white and back, every time when the key is pressed.
In the currently existing error state, the Led color does not change after pressing the key and uninterruptedly lights up white.
This applies to the notebook disregarding the actual active operating system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.